# Show/start video in blogger on image click

Tags: javascript, image, video, onclick, blogger

blogspot.co.il  is one of my blogger page.

I put in  every page a video.
now before the user sees the video, I'd like them to see [this image](http://i47.tinypic.com/2h4jjo2.jpg).
and only after the only when the user click on that image ,only then the video start playing.

This is the code for one of the pages:

```
<div dir="rtl" style="text-align: right;" trbidi="on">
  <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;">
    <br /><br />

    <div dir="rtl">
      <span style="color: #8e5353; font-size: x-large;"><b>-9- Part</b></span>
    </div>

    <div dir="rtl">
      <span style="color: #0000ee; font-size: x-large;"><b><u><a href="http://beingwithosho.blogspot.com/2013/05/9-part-broken-family.html">Broken Family. Blessing in disguise</a></u></b></span>
    </div>

    <br /><br /><br />

    <div>
      <div dir="rtl">
    </div>

    <div dir="ltr">
      <div class="video-container">
        <iframe height="375" src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0hozXLPGwkIa1dDTUpyUkpuQk0/preview" width="640"></iframe>
      </div>
      &nbsp;<b style="color: #0000ee; font-size: xx-large;"><u><br /></u></b>
    </div>

    <div class="separator" style="clear: both;">
    </div>

    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; direction: ltr;">
    </div>

    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: right;">
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: right;">
      <div style="direction: ltr; text-align: left;">
      </div>
      <div>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: right;">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You should find a way to make your question more succinct, perhaps through the use of a Minimum Working Example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look trick in this blog

http://beben-koben.blogspot.com/2013/05/trick-for-embed-video-youtube-to-be.html

i hope that useful